# Unable to loop through array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, arrayobject

I want to loop through an array of objects and i am unable to find the key's of each object. What am i doing wrong?

The Javascript / jQuery code:

```
var position = [];

$('.box').each(function(){

var id = $(this).attr('id');

var offset = $(this).offset();

var offsetX = offset.left;

var offsetY = offset.top;

position.push('{"id":'+id+',"offX":'+offsetX+',"offY":'+offsetY+'}');

});

for (var i = 0; i < position.length; i++) {
  console.log(position[i].id); // i get the error of undefined
}
```

Html markup:

```
<div id="parent">

    <div class="box" id="1">1</div>
    <div class="box" id="2">2</div>
    <div class="box" id="3">3</div>
    <div class="box" id="4">4</div>
    <div class="box" id="5">5</div>
    <div class="box" id="6">6</div>
    <div class="box" id="7">7</div>
    <div class="box" id="8">8</div>
    <div class="box" id="9">9</div>
    <div class="box" id="10">10</div>

</div>
```

Here the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ehaykzkm/)

Comment: Works fine http://jsfiddle.net/v4rshzrt/. Also, don't name it `Array`, it is an object provided by JS already. PascalCase is the convention for constructors, everything else should be camelCased.

Comment: `Array` is a builtin type constructor.

Comment: `Array` is the array constructor for arrays in javascript. Redefining it may make all sort of things go wrong.

Comment: funny, copy paste this code and completely works.

Comment: `undefined` is not an error here, it's the natural result of accessing `.id` on a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> position.push('{"id":'+id+',"offX":'+offsetX+',"offY":'+offsetY+'}');
> ```

Well, that's not an object but a JSON string (if you're lucky and it's valid). Use a proper object literal:

```
position.push({"id":id, "offX":offsetX, "offY":offsetY});
```

and then you will be able to access its `.id` property.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding a string to the array.  You want to add an object.

```
position.push({id: id,offX: offsetX,offY: offsetY});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had a look at your code and it seems that the problem lies with your statement:

```
$('.box').each(function(){});
```

Even tho the syntax is correct there can be other problems that cause this to happen. Here are a few suggestions that might be wrong with it:

- There is a missing JQuery file that you are referencing Or that you have not referenced a file at all.

Make sure you have the JQuery file for home testing/ServerTesting found on this site: [Click Here](http://jquery.com/download/)

- Make sure you have referenced the JQuery file in your script:

```
script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"
```

- If you are not running html 5 then make sure to add:

```
script type="javascript/text"
```

Comment: I included the jQuery file, anyway thank you for your interest